# How do you change Pixel Error in Unity3D terrain during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, unityscript

How do you change the Pixel Error, Base Map Distance, Cast Shadows, Tree Distance and other settings from runtime, not in inspector using UnityScript or C#?

I've tried looking in activeTerrain, an underneath there, Intellisense can't seem to see anything relating to what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I found the answer to it!

It's relatively easy when you reference the Component on Terrain. This script worked:

```
for(var gameObj : Terrain in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(Terrain)) {
        gameObj.GetComponent.<Terrain>().heightmapPixelError = 200;
        gameObj.GetComponent.<Terrain>().basemapDistance = 200;
        gameObj.GetComponent.<Terrain>().castShadows = false;
        gameObj.GetComponent.<Terrain>().treeDistance = 500;
        gameObj.GetComponent.<Terrain>().detailObjectDistance = 25;

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange...Is it possible that your IntelliSense is not working in the proper way?
**activeTerrain** should do the trick, because it contains **heightmapPixelError** (the value that you're indicating in your question's title), and all the other variables that you listed (**baseMapDistance**, **castShadows** and **treeDistance**). I link the [reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Terrain.html), just in case that you didn't looked at it yet...